# is pollution singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

is the word **pollution** singular or plural ?

The confusion delivered when making these statement `"pollution makes money, disease makes opportunity"`

Comment: In my mind it must be singular. Otherwise how could Captain Planet take pollution down to zero?

Comment: A group of researchers found that trans-Pacific air pollution **is** a hidden price of the goods sent abroad... - NYT

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nationality as mass noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140154/nationality-as-mass-noun)

Comment: 'Pollution' is a 'mass noun' which means grammatically it acts like a singular even though you can't see 'one' of them. See many examples explained here for example [nationality](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140154/nationality-as-mass-noun).

Comment: Because ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎unicornucopia.

Comment: Pollution is a singular noun even if it follows multiple nouns. For example, Land, water, and air pollution are/is of great concern to all people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pollution* is definitely singular, much like other uncountable nouns, such as *weather, love, information, water, furniture*...

Perhaps one thing that confused you is whether *"pollution"* is an abstract or concrete concept: but in fact, both abstract concepts (like *love*) and concrete objects (like *water*) can be uncountable. *Weather* and *pollution* seem to me to be in a vague middle ground, since we could argue both ways.