# Why would someone say “the American consumer” instead of "the American consumers"?

Tags: grammatical-number, definite-articles

As in "The Survey of the American Consumer" or "The state of the American consumer". Why is the phrase singular?

Comment: It's meant in the sense of a generic *individual*. As in "John Q. Public".

Comment: Note the definite article. "The consumer" refers to a class (consisting of all consumers in general.) Using the plural in this case would have meant referring to the individual consumers.

Comment: It's the same thing that happens in the sentence _the lion is the king of the animals_ or _the elephant is known for its culinary prowess_.

Comment: There seems to be some difficulty with the concept of _generic noun phrase_. [There are several kinds](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), using various articles.

Comment: Similar question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140154/nationality-as-mass-noun

Answer (score -1):

putting the word 'the' in front of American makes it singular. If you dropped the word 'the' then you could say American consumers.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything. *Why* is this phrase used this way?

Comment: no it doesn't but it does explain why it is singular instead of plural which is what you asked : "Why is the phrase singular?"

Maybe you could be more specific in your question next time.